# Can we use a Pandas function in a Spark DataFrame column ? If so, how?

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a pandas dataframe called "pd_df".

I want to modify it's column , so I do something like this:

```
    import pandas as pd

    pd_df['notification_dt'] = pd.to_datetime(pd_df['notification_dt'], format="%Y-%m-%d")
```

It works.

On the same database, I created a spark dataframe called "spark_df"

I want the same function (pd.to_datatime) on it's column to perform the same operation. So I did this.

```
    from pyspark.sql.functions import UserDefinedFunction

    from pyspark.sql.types import TimestampType

    udf = UserDefinedFunction(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, format="%Y-%m-%d"), TimestampType())

    spark_df2 = spark_df.withColumn("notification_dt1", (udf(spark_df["notification_dt"])))
```

It should work, according to me. However on

```
   spark_df.show()
```

I encounter the following error after a minute or so:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, got it fixed.

```
 udf = UserDefinedFunction(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, format="%Y-%m-%d"), TimestampType())
```

should be

```
 udf = UserDefinedFunction(lambda x: str(pd.to_datetime(x, format="%Y-%m-%d")), TimestampType())
```

It was basically failing to convert the result to TimestampType()